# Am I handling errors the good way with async/await functions and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

On my website, I use a lot of asynchronous functions to handle most part of my website, like creating an article, an administrator account, rendering a view, etc.

I got the habit to create as much async functions I need inside a controller, then execute all of them inside an async execution block, where I use a try { } catch () { } to catch any error. But I wonder if by using try { } catch () { } only on that block makes me miss some errors ?

Also, I use Mongoose with native Promises.

And, is that the good way to do it ?
I'm repeating this pattern since a lot of time so I wonder if I have to change half of my asynchronous functions.

Here is one controller example :

```
// getArticle {{{
  /**
   * Handles the view of an article
   *
   * @param {HTTP} request
   * @param {HTTP} response
   */
  getArticle: function (request, response) {
    /**
     * Get the article matching the given URL
     *
     * @async
     * @returns {Promise} Promise containing the article
     */
    async function getArticle () {
      let url = request.params.url

      return Article
        .findOne({ url: url })
        .populate('category', 'title')
        .exec()
    }

    /**
     * Asynchronous execution block
     *
     * @async
     * @throws Will throw an error to the console if it catches one
     */
    (async function () {
      try {
        let article = await getArticle()

        response.render('blog/article', {
          title: article.title,
          article: article
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }())
},
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - your solution is correct. You could have a lot of async function in controller, call them and handle errors in it. All errors will be handled in `catch` block.

But you don't need to add `async` to all these functions. If you don't want use result of async call in that function, just return the promise.

Also you don't need to wrap the controller's main code in the function, you could mark controller action as async function and add code inside it.

```
getArticle: async function(request, response) {
    function getArticle() {
      let url = request.params.url

      return Article
        .findOne({ url: url })
        .populate('category', 'title')
        .exec()
    }

    try {
      let article = await getArticle();

      response.render('blog/article', {
        title: article.title,
        article: article
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see, but I find it funnier and more pleasing to my eyes to see a ton of 'async' prefixes, is there any difference for the execution time if I do it the way you suggest me ?

Comment: Yes, there is a big difference, take a look at this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5wnsbc/async_functions_performance_question/

Comment: I see then, I will rewrite my asynchronous code. Many thanks.

Comment: If the documents aren't found it won't throw - `result.ok` will be true but `result.nModified` will be 0, this is still technically an error as far as the app is concerned in most cases since it didn't operate on what it was trying to find.

Comment: What about are you talking? if document not found, `findOne` return null.